# Newline does not write using Flask - service

Tags: python, flask

I hope somebody can help me on this problem. It has taken me a few days already trying to figure this out.

The Flask-service is able to write content using python's open library into a text file in a shared folder. The problem is, it does not write the newline character. It only writes in a single continuous line.

I have already tried the following combinations:
*I have tried `wb+`,`w`,`a+` and `w/wout` newline parameter in the open command. Running the code in my machine works fine using my local copy of the Flask-service. The only problem is, when Flask (from the server) is the one writing the content (even in to its own d: drive), then the newline does not get written.

```
value = [{10.10.10, 'test.test.com2'}, {10.10.10, 'test.test.com1'}]


with open(temp_file, 'a+') as file:
        for entry in value:
                for key in entry:
                        key_value = str(key).strip()
                        item_value = str(entry[key]).strip()
                        hosts_line = key_value + '\t' + item_value + '\r\n'
                        file.write(hosts_line)
```

Comment: What happens when you try just `hosts_line = key_value + '\t' + item_value + '\n'`?

Comment: The same. The newline does not get written. I also tried "\r" and their corresponding ascii characters.